# Should we remove these spoilers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, spoilers

[Why did Professor X smile before being killed by the Phoenix?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40002/why-did-professor-x-smile-before-being-killed-by-the-phoenix#40002) has a spoiler right in the title. It doesn't really bother me for some reason, but it might bother other users so I thought I'd bring it up on meta here. What do you think? Should we remove these spoilers?

Comment: Would it still be a spoiler if someone removed "by the Phoenix" from the title?

Comment: @anaranjada it'd be a less detailed spoiler.

Answer (score 0):

> It really is not much of a spoiler as he does not end up dead. In the end it really is just a mid point drama piece.

There spoiler tag! Sorry about that...

Comment: This whole post needs to be behind a spoiler tag :-)